# Testing appcelerator arrowdb production environment, how do I do this?

Tags: appcelerator, arrowdb

The tiapp.xml file holds keys for production and development environments.

I guess i could copy/paste and stuff in there to switch, but is it an easier way to test the production environment? Like some tag in the xml file such as "production=true" or something?

Comment: Simply copy/pasted it in the tiapp.xml for now... works. But ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tiapp.xml` should look something like:

```
<property name="appc-app-id" type="string">123</property>
<property name="acs-authbase-url-development" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-base-url-development" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-secret-development" type="string">123</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-key-development" type="string">123</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-development" type="string">123</property>
<property name="acs-username-development" type="string">appc_app_user_dev</property>
<property name="acs-password-development" type="string">123</property>
<property name="acs-authbase-url-production" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-base-url-production" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-secret-production" type="string">123</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-key-production" type="string">123</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string">123</property>
<property name="acs-username-production" type="string">appc_app_user</property>
<property name="acs-password-production" type="string">123</property>
<property name="appc-org-id" type="string">123</property>
<property name="appc-creator-user-id" type="string">123</property>
```

As you can see the `-development` and `-production` suffix determine the environment it value will be used for. You can also leave out the suffix to use it on all environments.

Comment: Yeah, i just copied the production keys to the development to test it. But was wondering if there was some easier way like adding "development=true" or something...

Comment: When building your app use `--deploy-type development` to force development or `--deploy-type production` to force production.